# Flask/Jinja2 render multiple collection

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm creating a MongoDB web application using pymango, Flask and Jinja2.
In connect with the database and I have three collections, and I can insert new data in the collection but when I render in HTML using Jinja2 I get duplicated rows with same data twice basically.  I'm new to python and Jinja.

```
    enter code here
@app.route("/addcar", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def addcar():
    if request.method == "POST":
        cars = {
            "car_image": request.form.get("car_image"),
            "car_year": request.form.get("car_year"),
            "car_name": request.form.get("car_name"),
            "car_design": request.form.get("car_design"),
            "car_driver1": request.form.get("car_driver1"),
            "car_driver2": request.form.get("car_driver2")
        }
        
        specs = {
            "spec_engine": request.form.get("spec_engine"),
            "car_power": request.form.get("car_power"),
            "trasmission": request.form.get("trasmission")
        }
        
        stats = {
            "races": request.form.get("races"),
            "wins": request.form.get("wins"),
            "podiums": request.form.get("podiums"),
            "poles": request.form.get("poles"),
            "fast_laps": request.form.get("fast_laps"),
            "constructor_champ": request.form.get("constructor_champ"),
            "drivers_champ": request.form.get("drivers_champ"),
            "description": request.form.get("description")
        }
        
        mongo.db.cars.insert_one(cars)
        mongo.db.specs.insert_one(specs)
        mongo.db.stats.insert_one(stats)
        flash("Car Successfully Added")
        return redirect(url_for("get_cars"))
    return render_template("addcar.html")`
```

enter code here

```
    enter code here
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}

<div class="row row justify-content-center mt-4">
    {% for car in cars %}

    <div class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 840px;">

        <div class="row g-0">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <img src="{{ car.car_image }}" class="imgCard" alt="ferrari image">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">

                        <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Year</strong>: {{ car.car_year }}</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Name</strong>: {{ car.car_name }}</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Designer</strong>: {{ car.car_design }}</li>

                    </ul>
                    {% for spec in specs %}
                    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">


                        <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Engine</strong>: {{ spec.spec_engine }}</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Power</strong>: {{ spec.car_power }}</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Trasmission</strong>: {{ spec.trasmission }}</li>


                    </ul>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>


            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    {% endfor %}


</div>


    enter code here

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: In your jinja code, you have applied the for loop on the second list, so you are bound to have multiple copies of the html that is encapsulated in it. Try to not pass an iterable to the html so that you dont have to use a for loop for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your html file looks something like this, it will not show replicated statements.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}

<div class="row row justify-content-center mt-4">
    

    <div class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 840px;">

        <div class="row g-0">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <img src="{{ car['car_image'] }}" class="imgCard" alt="ferrari image">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">

                        <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Year</strong>: {{ car['car_year' }}</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Name</strong>: {{ car['car_name'] }}</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Designer</strong>: {{ car['car_design'] }}</li>
                    
                    </ul>
             
                    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">


                        <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Engine</strong>: {{ spec['spec_engine'] }}</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Power</strong>: {{ spec['car_power'] }}</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Trasmission</strong>: {{ spec['trasmission'] }}</li>


                    </ul>
            
                </div>


            </div>

        </div>

    </div>


</div>

{% endblock %}
```

In your flask views, change the return statement to this,

```
 return render_template("addcar.html", car=cars, spec=specs)
```

Assuming that the html written above is the

Comment: thanks for your input@Harris Minhas, but  I still have the same issue

Comment: I have added some more modifications to the answer. It will work now, it works for me.